# Reading and saving data from Excel file- How to parse a file - undefined method `to_f' for #<Array:0x1579b6a8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, import

I followed a tutorial on RailsCast about how to import data from Excel.

I would like to read my excel file and to tell him which information to read and save indicating the row to pick up. So I wrote something like that in my model (.rb) file:

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv<<column_names
    all.each do |repartition|
      csv<<repartition.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
    end
  end
end

def self.import(file)
  #Ouverture du fichier
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)

  #Lecture du fichier, lignes par lignes, en aveugle

  (1..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    @repartition=Repartition.new

  @repartition.fond_repartition_id=spreadsheet.row(4)
    @repartition.date_repartition=spreadsheet.row(3)
    @repartition.AssetAllocCash=spreadsheet.row(5)
    @repartition.AssetAllocEquity=spreadsheet.row(6)
    @repartition.AssetAllocBond=spreadsheet.row(7)
    @repartition.AssetAllocOther=spreadsheet.row(8)


#Sauvegarde de la ligne qui vient d'être lu
    repartition.save!
  #Depart prochaine ligne ou fin
  end
end


def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new(file.path, options={})
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, options={})
  when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, options={})
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end
```

And I wrote this code in my controller

```
def import
  Repartition.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to upload_path, notice: "Répartition effectuée avec succès"
end
```

I have the error message :

```
NoMethodError in RepartitionsController#import
undefined method `to_f' for #<Array:0x1579b6a8>
```

All my data are float attributes. Why do I have this error ?

Comment: Does it point you to a specific line in the stack trace?

Comment: If the stack trace is what I imagine it is... Yes it points to the line 22 of my model (.rb file). app/models/repartition.rb:22:in `block in import'
app/models/repartition.rb:18:in `import'
app/controllers/repartitions_controller.rb:6:in `import'

Comment: You're having that error because somewhere in your code, it's calling `to_f` on the array instead of the members of the array. The `Array` class itself doesn't have a `to_f` method

Comment: May this error has anything to do with the fact that all my attributes of the Table I want to read are float ?

Comment: I may have found my mistake. Can you tell me how to select one particular cell in an excel file ? Because when I write spreadsheet.row(3) I wanted actually to select one data, and not an array

Comment: This tutorial helped me understood how to parse a file. [link]http://lab2023.com/how-to-parse-excel-spreadsheets-in-rails.html[link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me.
To parse my excel file I did the following steps.

I am using the gem roo. So in my GemFile is the line:

```
gem 'roo', '~>2.1.0'
```

Then I ran the command line:

```
bundle install
```

In my controller :

```html
  def import
    Repartition.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to resultat_path, notice: "Répartition effectuée avec succès"
  end
```

Then in my model:

```html
  def self.open_file(file)
   case File.extname(file.original_filename)
   when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new(file.path, options={})
   when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, options={})
   when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, options={})
   else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
   end
  end


  def self.import(file_path)
   #Ouverture du fichier
   file = open_file(file_path)
   #Lecture du fichier
   (1..file.last_row).each do |i|
    row = file.row(i)

    @repartition=Repartition.new

  @repartition.fond_repartition_id=row[4]
     @repartition.date_repartition=row[3]

    @repartition.save!
    end
  end
```

Then to call the method, on the web page on which I want to interact, I wrote this:

```html
<%= form_tag import_repartitions_path, multipart: true do %>
 <%= file_field_tag :file %>
 <%= submit_tag "Importer", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**The mistake was** that I forgot to write (first of all)

```
row = file.row(i)
```

Then what I tried to read had the wrong name. In the schema of my database I had migrate my table with attribute "date_repartitio" instead of "date_repartitio**n**" 
And **the error to_f** was saying that instead of reading "date_repartition" which is a float (not a datetime I know) it was reading "date_repartitio" which is actually nothing existing.

But with this I do not yet have the code to avoid creating an entity each time I run the import method.